# Sum up the results of a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, summarization

I've created this little code and have troubles to sum up the results of the loop. Somebody can help me with it?

```
a = array(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1), dim=c(4,3))
b = array(c(0,0,0,0,0,1), dim=c(2,3))

dist <- array()
for (j in 1:2) { 
  for (i in 1:4) {
  dist <- sqrt (sum ((a[i, ]-b[j, ])^2))
  print(dist)
  }
}
```

I get 8 numbers as result, but can only display the last of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fill in your `dist` matrix as you go.

```
dist <- array(dim=c(4,2))
for (j in 1:2) {
  for (i in 1:4) {
    dist[i,j] <- sqrt (sum ((a[i,1:3]-b[j,1:3])^2))
  } 
}
dist
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use the `outer` function (if someone comes up with a better way to vectorize the anonymous function, please feel free to edit)

```
(dist <- outer(1:4, 1:2, FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y)sqrt(sum((a[x,]-b[y,])^2)))))
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.732051 1.414214
[2,] 1.732051 1.414214
[3,] 1.732051 1.414214
[4,] 2.449490 2.236068
```

`1:4` is used to index `a`, and `1:2` is used to index `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the inbuilt `dist` function and avoid all these nested for loops

`dist` calculates the euclidean distance (the default from   number of possibilities). This appears to be what you want.

See `?dist` for more details

```
# give a and b some rownames

row.names(a)  <- paste0('a',1:nrow(a))
row.names(b)  <- paste0('b',1:nrow(b))
#combine into one matrix
ab <- rbind(a,b)

# get the distance between the points

distances <- as.matrix(dist(ab))

# subset those you are interested in
distances[row.names(a),row.names(b)]

##           b1       b2
## a1 1.732051 1.414214
## a2 1.732051 1.414214
## a3 1.732051 1.414214
## a4 2.449490 2.236068
```